# Can you forward a locale to a language in nextjs i18n?

Tags: next.js, internationalization

Let's say I support the languages `['en', 'de']`, then I want to redirect requests with a header of e.g `Accept-Language: de-DE` to `de`, because it's the closest thing I support.

```js
// This is my i18n config
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en', 'de']
  }
};

// Sample requests
// Accept-Language: de-DE    => goes to /en but should be /de
// Accept-Language: en-US,de => goes to /de but should be /en
```

So basically if the user requests a specific locale that I don't have, but I support the general language, the user should get that language. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you using any additional i18n third-party library?

Comment: @juliomalves yes I am (next-i18next), but according to the maintainer, all the localization logic is handled by nextjs directly (https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/issues/1412#issuecomment-915118586)

Comment: Are those the full `Accept-Language` header values in your sample requests? If not, could you had the full value you see in the request?

Comment: @juliomalves yes those are the full header values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Using the [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) method

---

You'll have to set the `localDetection` to `false`

> When localeDetection is set to false Next.js will no longer automatically redirect based on the user's preferred locale and will only provide locale information detected from either the locale based domain or locale path as described above.

Setting `localDetection` to false will allow us to choose the closest match language, **You should still provide the `defaultLocale` and the `locales` you support**

```js
// next.config.js expected to look like
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en', 'de', ...],
    localeDetection: false
  }
};
```

I use this [`function`](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/110c2f859db62398ae76069f4a6c5642), I found on GitHub, to find the closest matching locale

Using the [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) function, we can access the [`request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) object and it's `Accept-Language` header, get the closest locale and use the `redirect` property to set the locale.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({
  req,
  locale,
  locales,
  defaultLocale,
}) {
  const closestLocale = findClosestLocale(locales, [
    ...new Set([
      ...getLocales(req.headers["accept-language"], locale),
      locale,
      defaultLocale,
    ]),
  ]);

  if (
    (locale !== defaultLocale || closestLocale !== defaultLocale) &&
    locale !== closestLocale
  ) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination: `/${closestLocale}`,
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    // will be passed to the page component as props
    // (if there's no need to redirect)
    props: {},
  };
}
```

I created this simple function to get the locales from the `Accept-Language` header. I think this should be okay, but I'll assume there are other functions that cover more cases.

```js
function getLocales(str, defaultLocale) {
  return (
    str
      ?.split(",")
      .map((type) => type.split(";")[0].trim().replace("*", defaultLocale)) ??
    ""
  );
}
```

---

On [`Automatic Locale Detection`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#automatic-locale-detection), Next.js says

> When a user visits the application root (generally /), Next.js will try to automatically detect which locale the user prefers based on the Accept-Language header and the current domain.

We prevent this functionality when setting `localDetection` to `false`, so It will be fine to just export the `getServerSideProps` function from the `pages/index` file alone. Forcing that file to use `Server-side` render

---

In my example, I hardcoded the requested locale to 'nl-BE' which will be matched with the `nl` language.

[image: Open in StackBlitz]

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see how this answers the question. I essentially use no library for the localization part and sub path routing is activated by default, so I am using that too. But I still don't understand how to forward locales to languages, like explained in my question.

Comment: @MauriceNino, I've searched and haven't found any straightforward method or package. One method i've thought of, is to not use Next.JS's server and use a custom one, or we use the [`data-fetching`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) methods to get the `Accept-Language` header and route to the closest locale, or we handle the redirects on the client-side.

Comment: A server-side solution would be the only one that works for me.

Comment: Would you mind creating an example of what you mean with `data-fetching methods`?

Comment: @MauriceNino, I added an example. Check the edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks very promising. I will award you the bounty, although I can't check it right now. If I notice any problems along the line, I will make sure to comment them here, because I think this topic can potentially help other people.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. Just let me know if you encounter any other issues. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it and it worked perfectly! There are just a few minor errors: The header is always lowercase, so it should be `req.headers['accept-language']` & You have a spelling mistake in the `getLocales` function - `defaultLocale` vs `locale`. Also, I just want to add that the function you linked is a bit overkill, so I implemented my own.

Comment: Here is a full implementation snippet of my working code: https://gist.github.com/MauriceNino/bcb3d7361148153c4c7da84ffe128d39

Comment: Brilliant @MauriceNino, yeah I thought the matching function was a bit much. I see you return the translations from the `getServerSideProps` too. Glad the idea worked well for you. If you still encounter any issues. Just let me know